# Finding the Custom Properties of a rig in the dope sheet or the graph editor

Tags: animation, graph-editor, dopesheet

I'm attempting to figure out if there is a simple way to find the custom properties of a rig in the dope sheet or graph editor. In the rain rig, for example, there is a custom property called "dummy eyes." I've set some keys on it, and I'd like to find those keys in the graph editor or the dope sheet. However I am unable to do so. I've looked through all the bones of the rig, making sure to hit alt-h in case there were any hidden bones and still could not find the attribute anywhere. Can anyone help with this?

> > Edit- I've added an image of the "character" subheader of the "Cloudrig" addon tab which contain the properties that don't appear on anywhere on the dope sheet or graph editor;
> > [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any animation channel, including animated custom properties, will be listed under the bone on which it lives. If it lives on the armature itself, it'll be listed separately, under the armature name.
To find a specific property you can use the search field at the top of the channel list in either the graph editor or the dopesheet.

[image]

Comment: It would seem that certain properties on the rig "Rain," don't follow this logic. It's a rig that uses the 'CloudRig' addon and properties that are under the "character" subheader of the Cloudrig tab (such as "Dummy eyes," "Mask legs," etc) cannot be found on any bone.

Comment: If you hover over these properties you will see a popup appear telling you where they are. In this case they're on a bone named "Properties_Character_Rain" sitting in armature layer 30. You can select those bones, keyframe the properties in question and once they appear in the graph/dopesheet, pin the channels.

Comment: Oh fantastic, thanks very much! I don't have that info in the pop when I hover over the property, only a message that  says "Dummy eyes for animators to get a better sense of eye lines. Doesn't show up on render." Did you configure your blender in such a way to have more info come up when you hover over a property? In any case, it was indeed in the layer 30, so thank you very much for that!

Comment: Ah yes, it must be "Python tooltips" somewhere in preferences.

Comment: ah indeed, thanks again! you've helped me greatly on my blender journey.